# What is the meaning of tawqeef and ijtihad of sahabah?

Tags: practical-islam

I would like to know the meaning of the expressions tawqeef, and ijtihad of sahabah in the context of the quote below.

> There's a kind of difference of opinion on whether the names of the
>   surahs of the qur'an are proven to be given by the prophet () through
>   divine guidance (this is often referred to as tawqeef التوقيف in
>   Arabic language) or whether they are based on ijtihad of the sahabah
>   () as we know the collection and compilation of the qur'an in one book
>   has been established after the time of the prophet ().

I want to understand better the answer given to a question I [asked](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/how-were-the-surahs-of-the-quran-named) in the past.

May Allah give me wisdom and may include me in the Ummah.

Comment: Ijtihad should be clear. Tawqeef is something there's no Ijtihad about.

Comment: If it were clear to me, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: The question already contains its answer. All terms are explained in the quote itself.

Comment: Thank you! I'll flag this question to be closed, since it already has a answer [there](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/how-were-the-surahs-of-the-quran-named), this one doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sahaba in that context means the so called companions of the prophet

Tawqeef means through divine guidance.

Ijtihad of Sahabah means through own effort witouth divine guidance.

(Thanks Medi1Saif for the clarifications ([here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/52374/29714) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/58400/what-is-the-meaning-of-tawqeef-and-ijtihad-of-sahabah/59441#comment96128_58400)))

Answer (score 1):

Tawqeef means to acquaint. In the context of the quote it means that the names have been conveyed by Allah through revelation. Ijtihad means exertion of utmost effort by oneself. In the context of the quote it means that the names were selected by sahabah through their own reasoning.